# How to create multi-dimensional matrices as input to neural network?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, feature-extraction

I am trying to create a neural network with a multi-dimensional input matrix. Input could be of size 2x7, 8x7 or any such dimension with 7 columns. (This input is used in for loop structure shown below)

My question is, How to create a training DataFrame that could contain multiple such matrices with different dimensions to feed the neural network? I tried training model on for loop for every matrix but there should be some more suitable method for creating such a dataset.

Note: I am trying to get a single input with all such different dimensional matrices and that could easily map to their respective outputs. So input should look like (a, b, 7) where **a** is the number of data points that are matrices with different lengths of rows, **b** is the number of rows in that particular matrix and 7 is the number of columns in all the matrices.

The data is an example of time-series data that users created by time. So I need to keep each row of single matrices in its order. And the output will generate the next time a user creates a new row. Please understand, the focus of this question is not the model but how to represent this data for the model.

Here's the code to my model:

```
model.add(Lambda(lambda x: tf.expand_dims(x, axis=1), input_shape=[7]))
model.add(Dense(2048, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(1024, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(512, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(216, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(7, activation='tanh'))
model.summary()
```

My loop to fit model looks like this:

```
for user_id in user_ids:
    df = dailytable[dailytable['user_id']==user_id]
    if df.shape[0] > 3:
        X = df.iloc[:-1, :]
        Y = df.iloc[-1, :]
        Y = tf.reshape(Y, (1, 7))
        if len(X.axes[0].tolist()) > 3:
            model.fit(X, Y, epochs=5, steps_per_epoch=1)
```

I want to create some data structure which contains all my matrices. It would look like a 3-dimensional matrix. And all those matrices have different input shapes as explained above. But have the same output i.e, 1x7. Instead of using the loop structure, I want to pass a single input at the start of training.

Comment: What about zero padding? This would make all your input equal in size.

Comment: The length of the columns is equal in all the matrices. But all of them have different number of rows. Is it a good solution to add zero padding for extra rows?

Comment: Yea why not? Zeros will not be weighted during training anyways.

Comment: You should not use padding for such cases, instead, you can use the Lambda layer from TensorFlow with extra_dim function to have varying rows of a matrix.

Comment: Can you post your training loop code? (Or, just all of your code?) Then it will be much easier to help out.

Comment: I agree with @cwindolf. In addition, could you please be more precise on the expected input and output shapes? For example, are you talking about mapping tensors of shape `(batch_size, variable_size, 7)` to `(batch_size, 7)` , or do you rather mean from `(variable_batch_size, 7)` to `(variable_batch_size, 7)`? Or from `(batch_size, variable_size, 7)` to `(batch_size, variable_size, 7)`?

Comment: Please check the updated question. I am just trying to get all such different dimensions of matrices into a single input but I don't know the method to do it.

Comment: I couldn't understand why not simply concatenate these training batches, If this not what you want, please give more clarification, because using 7 columns and various number of rows seems to be just batches from the training set.

`x1 = np.random.randn(5,7)
y1 = np.random.randn(3,1)

x2 = np.random.randn(3,7)
y2 = np.random.randn(3,1)


stackX = np.concatenate([x1, x2],axis=0)
stackY = np.concatenate([y1, y2],axis=0)`

Comment: As per your suggestion, this will create stackX of shape (8,7) and stackY of shape (6,1). Again in this array I won't have any way of keeping track of row of individual matrices.

Answer (score 0):

Modelling any temporal series has the same problem. You should take a look at CNNs or RNNs since they admit variable dimensions. In the case of the CNN you can have an input with 7 channels and variable length.

With a fully connected layer you have an input with fixed shape. So you either apply zero padding to fulfill the maximum size as already suggested or use as input the windowed shifted signal (which is what the CNN does).

Comment: Please check the updated question. I am asking about the type of input to be used. I understand that CNN inputs have shape of about (128, 128, 3) where 3 is the RGB channels of that image. But here there are no images instead, these are series information of individuals that is a single matrix of (b, 7). I want all these matrices under one input which would look like (a, b, 7).

Comment: I was talking about [1D convolutions](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#conv1d). But seeing your updated question, one common approach to obtain a single value out of a sequence is to take the last hidden value of a RNN (e.g. [LSTM](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.LSTM)). But if you still want to use this data strucure, you can do it by storing each matrix in a list. So resulting shapes [[7, 1], [7,2], ...] and then you can choose the network as list[input.shape[1]](input). Though this is not recommended because shapes are not traceable.